# Can we draw an unbounded four dimensional object?

Tags: geometry

I am familiar with the idea of a tesseract. And in all the descriptions of four dimensional geometry, the images are of cubes, spheres, boxes, polyhedra ... closed structures where vertices are connected. Typically these drawings begin with the three dimensional projections which are connected at their vertices.. But what about paraboloids, starbursts, nautilus shells?

It gets hard knowing where to draw the ‘connections’ between the three dimensional primitives.

Is there another way to represent a four dimensional object as an array of the three dimensional projections? Just as we might have a notation to represent a 3D cube as an array of 2d squares , could we represent a hyper cube as an array of solids?

This would be more generalizable to the unbound objects I mentioned earlier as we as objects with discontinuities or other weirdness (Möbius bands , Klein bottles...)

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/599877.The_Shape_of_Space